# Angularjs how pass Multiple parameters and header values

Tags: angularjs, angular-http

Error
Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the

```
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);
myApp.controller('TestingCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
    var GetData = function () {

        $http({
            method: "GET",
            url: 'http://103.22.11.11/Buses/Sources'

        }).success(function (response) {
            $scope.Return = response.Id[0];
            alert("ddd");

        })
    }
    GetData();
})
```

how can i pass this headers

```
                'ConsumerKey': '811D72785AC287ACE3E8',
                'ConsumerSecret': 'C80A758DCC6BCEBE436D25BC'
```

Comment: Are your custom headers allowed on your server side by using `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` in your backend response? Its the most common error.

Comment: It should be a server side issue, set access control on server side, or try `JSONP` instead of `GET` in the method.

Comment: i check Chrome ARC Are Working but Seperat file not working

Comment: Please answer the users questoins in the comments. This `i check Chrome ARC Are Working but Seperat file not working` does not make sense at all.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try like below.

```
  var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);
    myApp.controller('TestingCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
    var GetData = function () {

        $http({
            method: "GET",
            url: 'http://103.22.11.11/Buses/Sources',
            data:{'dummy':'dummy'},
            headers: {'Content-Type':'application/json',
             'ConsumerKey': '811D72785AC287ACE3E8',
                'ConsumerSecret': 'C80A758DCC6BCEBE436D25BC'}

        }).success(function (response) {
            $scope.Return = response.Id[0];
            alert("ddd");

        })
    }
    GetData();
   });
```

Comment: Thats exactly what he asked, see the edit: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/41697263/revisions